# Generate a const typed object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to generate a `const` typed object by passing in a string I want to use as the type, is this possible, I have tried the below and it's bringing out the wrong type.

```
const test = <T> (name: T) => {
  const hi: { name: T } = {
    name
  } as const
  return hi
}

const test1 = test('hello')
```

I'd like this to be of type

```
{
    name: 'hello';
}
```

But instead it's of type

```
{
    name: string;
}
```

Comment: You need to write `test('hello' as const)`, otherwise it'll infer `test<string>(…)`.

Comment: You are pretty close, the bit missing is mostly `as const` on `hello`.

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCoD4AUYAhgLYoBci2AlIgN4BQiiATilCC0nYsWYgF8A3AwEMGEBBmTooARkQBeGRnwByABYoANtrhrERNIklgM1IA

Comment: Awesome... only trouble is i'm trying to get away from developers having to write `as const` as I think they will miss this bit out, is there a way to enforce this, or have a function that will add this in for me as a helper?

Comment: Why do you want to force developers to use constant string types? What's the problem if they use `string`?

Comment: Just add appropriate constraint. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEGAvm). No need to use `as const`

Comment: Perfect thank you @captain-yossarian that is exactly what I need.  Bergi, the reason I want to force users is so that when this is used elsewhere it gives the user intellisense of the values been chosen.  If they add just a string it breaks the intellisense and the typeScript validations.

Comment: Note in the example @captain-yossarian you can also skip the `as const` and infer the type inside the function, [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YB4AqN4A8FgBMIZoAnASzAHMA+ACjAEMBbeALhgwEoUaYBvAFAwRMUJFgALcigHDRCpq3kiAvipil4UAK6kwMaYPWDxSBNACMsi1DoBySfAA2zkPa5A).

Comment: @Bergi in answer to your question “ Why do you want to force developers to use constant string types? What's the problem if they use string” I want to enforce this, as I want to force the intellisense to provide a list of available types for them to choose from.  There will be an array of these generated objects used somewhere and the types to be as an arg to a helper function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to infer literal type of an argument, usually you need to add appropriate constraint to your generic argument.
See this example:

```js
function test<T extends string>(name: T) {
  return { name };
}

const test1 = test('hello') // {name:"hello"}
```

If you are interested in more examples, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

If you want to add some validation, you can use conditional type:

```js
// Forbids using underscore as a prefix
type IsAllowed<T extends string> = T extends `_${string}` ? never : T

function foo<T extends string>(name: IsAllowed<T>) {
  return { name };
}


const test1 = foo('hello') // ok 
const test2 = foo('_hello') // expected error
```

Or you may use this utility type :

```js
type IsLiteral<T extends string> = T extends string ? string extends T ? never : T : never

function test<T extends string>(name: IsLiteral<T>) {
  return { name };
}
```

If you want to allow only string literals

Comment: `function test<T extends string>(name: IsHello<T>) {` is a really long and convoluted way using conditional types to write `function test(name: 'hello') {` isn't it?

Comment: "*From my experience arises, that if you can't infer something with one generic - add another one. […] In order to make it work you need apply extra restrictions to `Value` generic.*" - interesting. Is this just a hack, or documented behaviour?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you can use `IsHello` only if you want to validate in some way literal type of `name` argument. It is just an example of [validation](https://catchts.com/validators). Feel free to get rid of `IsHello` and just use `test<T extends string>(name: T)`. And yes, sometimes typescript is a bit verbose if it comes to validation

Comment: @Bergi personally I don't treat it as a hack. It is just a more precise way of typing arguments. It arises only from my experience. I did not quote ts docs. Of course different people might have different point of views. TS is much verbose in comparison to other languages if it comes to types

Comment: @captain-yossarian No, I mean do you know whether it is a documented TypeScript feature that the existence of an `extends` clause affects type inference? Or is it just a coincidence and should not relied on?

Comment: Amazing guys thanks so much for your help, it has 100% answered what I was stuck on

Comment: @Bergi I have found these articles in the docs: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html), [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#improved-inference-for-generics), [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html). Maybe I have overlooked something because I did not find exact statement about such kind of inference. So, I'm not 100% sure whether this behavior documented or not. AFAIK, TS team constantly improves documentation.

Comment: @Bergi I think it worth asking somebody from TS team, maybe @ orta, he will know for sure whether it is documented or not and if this is reliable feature. I'm 99.99% sure that you can rely on this

Comment: I am happy to ask orta if you think that's important in internal Microsoft channels - but I think the `IsLiteral` behaviour is 100% documented/intentional if not in the docs in the release notes (I recall the PR but can't dig it up). My previous comment was just about how `IsHello` is unneeded since it widens then immediately narrows the type.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum my comment was related to Bergi's question. Yes, `IsLiteral` is a conditional type which is fully documented. No need to ask anybody from ts team. I was talking about literal inference. I think it is some sort of misunderstanding. `IsHello` is needed only if you want to make some validation

Comment: Sorry the lack of clarify was on my side - I meant the inference (regarding pinging orta). Regarding the literal the type `IsHello<T>` is identical to just `'hello'` (in the context of the question). Let me know if you'd like me to ping :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes, you are right, using `IsHello` is the same as using just literal `hello` type, however this is very trivial example of validation. Most of the time this technique is used to negate some type. For instance. your function expects a string argument, however you want to forbid all arguments which starts with underscore `_`. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/w8KZVW)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum  I have updated my answer, to make it more clear.

Comment: Neat, I have types that are >600 LoC of inferred conditional types (hate the syntax but large codebases mean the few very-common types benefit from this sort of thing). This is very usable since 4.5 which produces very nice resulting types. Some of it parses a whole DSL we use :D

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sounds very interesting. Unfortunatelly, I have never worked on a project where conditional types are heavily used :(

Comment: Biggest one is actually for security.microsoft.com imports, it parses a syntax our micro-frontend uses for dynamically importing another frontend (inferring the package and the import) and then grabs it from a big (auto-generated) list of `import type`s. Looks like quite a pyramid. The other big one is for our modeling layer (thing that converts JSON/gRPC from the backend into TS types), since we avoid decorators - it maps things like `{ foo: String }` into a type with `foo: string` recursively. Here is a small subset of `it https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/937efb344a0faa3f498be28f5d55e383

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Wooow!, looks like everybody doing something interesting at work except me :D

Comment: [We're hiring](https://careers.microsoft.com/) for pretty much everything everywhere :D Though to be fair I only get to work on these sort of problems because my team is in charge of dev-experience and is part of the FE-Infra organization. Anyway this is already OT enough as it is - nice chat :)

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, I have already applied to microsoft and they did not respond. This is very nice job though

Comment: @captain-yossarian feel free to send your CV over to bgruenbaum@microsoft.com and I'll submit it to the system (to be clear: I don't get anything from that (unless you submit to a job in Israel) but I was told it solves the "they did not respond" problem for a bunch of people) :)